# Elasticsearch circle - geo_shape query does not give the result I expected

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am facing with problem for radius at circle geo_shape.

Here my mapping;

```
PUT /circle-example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_shape",
        "strategy": "recursive"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here example index request

```
POST /circle-example/_doc
{
  "location" : {
    "type" : "circle",
    "coordinates" : [70.0, 1.0],
    "radius" : "25mi"
  }
}
```

When I calculate distance between [70.0, 0.0] and [70.0, 1.0], I found 23,63 miles (smaller than radius - 25 miles).
[distance between 2 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9WhD.png)

Therefore; I should find document when I search with query given at below

```
GET circle-example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "geo_shape": {
            "location": {
              "shape": {
                "type": "point",
                "coordinates": [
                  70.0, 0.0
                ],
                "relation": "contains"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However I did not receive correct result . Here screenshot belongs to answer;
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liKOx.png)

Which means; Elasticsearch says that [70.0, 0.0] is not in circle whose center is [70.0, 1.0] and radius is 25 miles.
However; distance between them is 23.63 miles and [70.0, 0.0] is in circle.

Could you say what is the problem at here ?

Answer (score 0):

In your coordinates array, the first component is the longitude not the latitude

```
  "coordinates": [
       70.0, 0.0
  ],
```

So if you correctly swap the values in your distance calculator, you're going to see that the distance between those two points is actually 69 miles and not 25 miles.

Adjusting the circle radius to 69 miles in your document will actually work and return the right document.

[image]